# Stackage LTS announces

Tags: stackage

How can I know that a new Stackage LTS was released? I couldn't find this information in Stackage [home page](https://www.stackage.org/) nor in this [FAQ section on Github](https://github.com/fpco/stackage#frequently-asked-questions).

Comment: This question is off-topic for the haskell tag.

Comment: @MichaelLitchard, you are right. I removed that tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My personal favorite is using the RSS feeds, e.g.

- https://www.stackage.org/feed (all snapshots)
- https://www.stackage.org/feed/lts (all LTS snapshots)
- https://www.stackage.org/feed/lts-11 (all LTS-11 snapshots)

Bonus is that you'll get to see the differences between each successive snapshot. Alternatively, you could watch the LTS Haskell Git repo:

- https://www.stackage.org/feed/lts-11